# File will not upload using laravel 5.7 forms

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I switched from the laravel collective forms of 5.4 to the forms of 5.7. everything was working perfectly until I switched and tried using the new forms. I'm trying to upload a simple picture with a text post. The text is uploaded in the database, but the picture/file is not. I'm not sure what I'm missing so if anyone can assist it would greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

home.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('makePost')  }}">
                            @csrf

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="body" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Body') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="body" type="text" class="form-control" name="body" value="{{ old('body') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="photo" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Photo') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="photo" type="file" class="form-control" name="photo" value="{{ old('photo') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Submit Post') }}
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

PostsController.php:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $user = Auth::user();

    if($file = $request->file('photo_id')) {
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('images', $name);
        $photo = Photo::create(['file'=>$name]);
        $input['photo_id'] = $photo->id;
    }

    $user->post()->create($input);
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Comment: show us your controller.

Comment: I have edited my post to include the controller. The controller worked fine before I switched from the laravelcollective forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if($file = $request->file('photo_id')) {
    $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->move('images', $name);
    $photo = Photo::create(['file'=>$name]);
    $input['photo_id'] = $photo->id;
}
```

Here you assume input has name `photo_id` but in your form you set name as `photo`:

```
<input id="photo" type="file" class="form-control" name="photo" value="{{ old('photo') }}">
```

So you should be consistent - use same name in all places - either `photo_id` or `photo`

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks much and I'll make sure to remember that for future reference so it doesn't happen again.